# csrf token error in dynamic form in django

Tags: javascript, python, django

I know the question similar to this has been asked before before I could not derive workable solution for my problem using those answers.

I have a page which has a form A and lots of checkboxes. The form and related checkboxes is created through Django Templates. I created a new form B via javascript from the the input values of the form A created by Django Template. Django is not accepting my new form B due to csrf_token error. Can somebody show me how to extract csrf token from the form A rendered by django and use it as csrf token for the dynamically created javascript form?

Comment: Do you post the data collected from generated form `b` to form `a`'s action so django thinks it's form `a`?

Comment: No, I am creating an entirely new form and disregarding old form alltogether.

Comment: ok so apart from all input fields, can you also add the csrf token hidden field to the new form before posting it?

Answer (score 3):

You can include the csrf token in the data your posting.

You can either extract it from the hidden field in the html form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="IxwFarTrerVBZbVDX0elVHUEbh0YH58j">
```

using a jquery selector:

```
var token = $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val();
```

Or if you prefer plain js as you have mentioned you can use this function to extract it from the document cookies:

```
function getCookie(name) {
    var v = document.cookie.match('(^|;) ?' + name + '=([^;]*)(;|$)');
    return v ? v[2] : null;
}

var token = getCookie('csrftoken');
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a simpler approach would be to use cookies. A csrf token is just a cookie whose value you can retrieve. Kindly look at the section on `Ajax` and see if it can offer any help https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/csrf/#ajax.

`var csrftoken = Cookies.get('csrftoken');`

Doing that using the javascript cookie library should ideally help you to retrieve the csrf token.

Comment: How would you add cookie to dynamically generated form to that django accepts it?

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades After generating the form do you post it as an ajax POST request or the normal form submit

Comment: Is there something native js to solve this? I want to avoid extra js library as much as possible.

Comment: In the code dynamic code for generating the form can you add something like this:
`var csrftoken = Cookies.get('csrftoken');`
`<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="+ csrftoken +">`

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades Sure. You can look at `document.cookie` and do string splits on it.